# Which position do retro aldol reactions occur in (comparing glucose and fructose)?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, organic-chemistry

Regarding glycolysis, my text states:

> What is the biochemical rationale for the isomerization of glucose 6-phosphate to fructose 6-phosphate and its subsequent phosphorylation to form fructose 1,6-bisphosphate? Had the aldol cleavage taken place in the aldose glucose, a two-carbon and a four-carbon fragment would have resulted. Two different metabolic pathways, one to process the two-carbon fragment and one for the four-carbon fragment, would have been required to extract energy.

I am trying to understand this and I found [this](https://www.mdpi.com/molecules/molecules-21-00937/article_deploy/html/images/molecules-21-00937-sch001.png) diagram. It seems that glucose undergoes a [4+2] retro aldol reactions but fructose undergoes [3+3]. Why is this? What determines which position a retro aldol decomposition occurs in? Is there any particular reason glucose could not undergo [3+3] decomposition?

Comment: If you have found a diagram, please present it in your question, as questions here should be self-contained. Also give details of your text. I suspect, however, that your question — when properly formulated — may attract more responses on SE Chemistry.